# Obtener valores de multiples checkbox en Angular 8

Tags: mysql, angular, typescript, interfaz-gráfica

Buen dia

Estoy desarrolando una app en Angular 8, esta app posee un administrador de usuarios el cual tiene un apartado con varios checkboxes donde puedes seleccionar el foro o foros a los cuales el usuario podra accesar, el problema es que con el codigo que les mostrare a continuacion solo toma uno solo checkbox aun cuando seleccione varios. Estuve investigando un poco y comentan que esto se tendria que hacer con un array pero no se como estructurarlo. La idea es que una vez seleccionados los checkboxes por el usuario y alojados en el array, este array se guarde en el campo Foros de mi table MySQL.

Codigo HTML

```
<div class="main-checkbox">
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <div id="checkbox-container">
      <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" color="warn" [(ngModel)]="autoevaluacion" (change) = "foroMostrar()">Autoevaluación</mat-checkbox>
      <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" color="warn" [(ngModel)]="revisiontalentofuncionarios" (change) = "foroMostrar()">Revisión de Talento Funcionarios</mat-checkbox>
      <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" color="warn" [(ngModel)]="reporteadores">Reporteadores</mat-checkbox>
      <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" color="warn" [(ngModel)]="reporteadoresgerentes">Reporteadores Gerentes</mat-checkbox>
      </div>

      <div id="checkbox-container2">
      <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" color="warn" [(ngModel)]="revisiontalentogerentes">Revisión Talento Gerentes</mat-checkbox>
      <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" color="warn" [(ngModel)]="contratodesempenofuncionarios">Contrato Desempeño Funcionarios</mat-checkbox>
      <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" color="warn" [(ngModel)]="revisiontalentojefes">Revisión Talento Jefes Departamento</mat-checkbox>
      <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" color="warn" [(ngModel)]="contratodesempenogerentes">Contrato Desempeño Gerentes</mat-checkbox>

      </div>

          </div>
```

Codigo TS

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-administrador-usuarios',
  templateUrl: './administrador-usuarios.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./administrador-usuarios.component.css']
})
export class AdministradorUsuariosComponent implements OnInit {

  public agregarUsuario =  false;
  public showButton = true;
  public rol:string;
  public foro = '';
  public autoevaluacion:boolean;
  public revisiontalentofuncionarios:boolean;


  public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA)
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['nombre', 'correo', 'rol', 'foros','editar', 'eliminar'];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {



  public foroMostrar(){


    if(this.autoevaluacion == true){
     console.log(this.autoevaluacion)
     this.foro = "autoevaluacion"
     console.log("El foro seleccionado es:", this.foro)
    }



    if(this.revisiontalentofuncionarios == true){
      this.foro = ''
      console.log(this.foro)
      this.foro = "revisiontalentofuncionarios"
      console.log("El foro seleccionado es:", this.foro)
     }

  }

}
```

De antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Los puedes realizar utilizando un array de la siguiente manera.

HTML

```
<div>
    <div *ngFor="let foro of foros">
        <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="foro.checked"/>
        <label>{{foro.nombre}}</label>
    </div>
    <pre>{{ foros | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

Component TS

```js
export class AppComponent {
  public foros: Array<Object> = [
    { nombre: "foro1", checked: false },
    { nombre: "foro2", checked: false },
    { nombre: "foro3", checked: false },
    { nombre: "foro4", checked: false }
  ];
}
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Esta genial la solución, una pregunta ¿para los radiobuttons sería lo mismo? saludos